# Prevent access to dependencies in examples in Rust project?

Tags: rust

I am making a library in `rust`, and I learned that I could put example usages of the library in an `examples` directory in the root directory and then run them with `cargo run --example hello`. However, I noticed that the dependencies I specify in `Cargo.toml` are also available in the example code. This is a bit odd to me. These dependencies belong to the library and the user shouldn't be aware of them and certainly not use them himself (unless he happens to depend on them too, I guess).

For example, I have `nalgebra = "0.31.0"` in `Cargo.toml` and use it as a backend for vectors and matrices and other mathematical operations.

I created my own wrappers for vectors and matrices, so the user shouldn't access `nalgebra` types directly. I find it weird that when writing examples for the library, I can write `use nalgebra as na;` and use it without any issues. I guess it's helpful for debugging purposes, but when writing a complete example, this code shouldn't compile.

Is there a way to generate compiler errors when trying to use dependencies in example code, or is it simply my responsibility to write examples that reflect actual usage of the library?

Comment: If it's confusing to your users if you use your lib's dependencies in examples, maybe the solution is to just _not_ use your lib's dependencies in examples?

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the issue. You are writing the examples, not your users. It is your responsibility to shape the examples as you see fit.

Comment: The OP explicitly acknowledge they should not use the dependencies, but they ask for a way to _disallow_ them to use them so they'll not do it mistakenly. To be honest, I agree this is bad that examples can use dependencies, but I'm afraid there's no such option.

Comment: The available dependencies in the examples are not identical to the available dependencies that the user can see.

If you create a new project and specify your library as a dependency, you will see that the dependencies of your library do not get exposed to the new project. Yes, it is your responsibility to write examples that actually work. If you would write a library that interacts with other libraries, you most certainly **would** want to use the dependencies in the examples. But currently, there is no separate `[dependencies]` tab in the toml for examples.

Comment: A reasonable way to get this would be to have a second package in the same [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html) that only contains examples. Alternatively, you could make the examples full packages on their own, each with its own set of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> is it simply my responsibility to write examples that reflect actual usage of the library?

Yes.

This comes up in other situations too: as long as you're writing code inside a single Cargo package, all that code shares a common set of dependencies (with the exception that `[dev-dependencies]` are not available to `lib` and `bin` targets, only `test`, `example`, and `bench` targets).

If you want a different set of dependencies, the only option is to split the example(s) into a separate package (which can be in a *workspace* with the library package). In my experience, it's somewhat common for Rust projects to have a separate package for examples, particularly when those examples have shared code; for example, a graphics library whose examples need window-management code might have structure like

```
Cargo.toml          # workspace declaration
the-library/
    Cargo.toml
    src/
        lib.rs
examples/
    Cargo.toml      # has a `{ path = "../the-library" }` dependency
    src/
        lib.rs      # contains setup code the examples use
    examples/
        ex1.rs
        ex2.rs
```

There is a disadvantage to doing this: your examples won't be included in the package uploaded to the registry, and the new `rustdoc` feature that shows snippets of examples in the docs of functions that they use, won't find these examples.

---

However, if your *only* concern is “the examples shouldn't refer to this library”, then probably the best option is to take care writing the examples.

You can also use `clippy` to check for unwanted mentions of functions or types, with the [`disallowed_methods`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#disallowed_methods) and [`disallowed_types`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#disallowed_types) lints. However, the lists of disallowed items are package-wide configuration, so you'd have to specifically disable the lint inside your library so that clippy doesn't warn on *those* uses of the dependency.